# Saving highscore with NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm *trying* to load up my saved highscore in swift using `NSUserDefaults` however it's just loading up, I've run through as many tutorials as I can find but it's left me scratching my head as my `Highscore` doesn't want to load up.  Would anyone be able to spot why?

All of the below code is in `GameScene.Swift`

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    highScoreLabelNode.fontName = "Helvetica-Bold"
    highScoreLabelNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2.6, y: self.frame.size.height / 1.3 )
    highScoreLabelNode.fontSize = 20
    highScoreLabelNode.alpha = 0.2
    highScoreLabelNode.zPosition = -30
    highScoreLabelNode.text = "Highscore \(score)"

    var highScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if (highScoreDefault.valueForKey("HighScore") != nil){
    highScore = highScoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") as! NSInteger!
    highScoreLabelNode.text = NSString(format: "Highscore : %i", highScore) as String
     }
        self.addChild(highScoreLabelNode)

}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if (score > highScore) {
        highScore = score
        highScoreLabelNode.text = NSString(format: "Highscore : %i", highScore) as String

        var highscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        highscoreDefault.setValue(highScore, forKey: "Highscore")
        highscoreDefault.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you gave, you are setting "Highscore" when updating, but are attempting to get the value for "HighScore" (Notice the capital S)

This line:

```
if (highScoreDefault.valueForKey("HighScore") != nil){
```

Change it to:

```
if (highScoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") != nil){
```

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults has an explicit method to read and write integer values.

replace

```
var highScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if (highScoreDefault.valueForKey("HighScore") != nil){
    highScore = highScoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") as! NSInteger!
    highScoreLabelNode.text = NSString(format: "Highscore : %i", highScore) as String
}
```

with

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
highScore = defaults.integerForKey("Highscore")
highScoreLabelNode.text = "\(highScore)"
```

If you register the key as [Apple recommends](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH3-SW1), you can use a non-optional variable

Comment: This is not great (though works), because it will return 0 if the value is not yet stored, which might not be appropriate as you have no way to tell if the value exists.

Comment: If you register the key/value pair in AppDelegate – which is the usual way – you can  provide a custom default value which is read if no value has been written yet. Then the value is never nil and you don't need any optional binding.

Answer (score 0):

Values are case sensitive, hence the value not found error. You are storing value as "Highscore" but reading it as "HighScore", which will always be empty. Just change the keys are you are golden :)

Also, don't use != nil as it is ineffective and not needed in swift; Instead, use if let syntax, like this:

```
if let highScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("Highscore") as? Int {
    highScoreLabelNode.text = String(format: "Highscore : %d", highScore)
}
```

This makes your code much more readable and you will find that it is much easier to write. You can read more about "optional chaining" in the [Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).

Hope it helps!